# Wrong result: a continuous function has zero $p$-variation, for every $p$. Where's the error?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, bounded-variation

Let $\Pi_n$ be a sequence of partitions with $|\Pi_n| \to 0$. Then the $p$-variation of a continuous function $g$ along the partitions $\Pi_n$ is defined as

$$V_T^p(g) = \lim_{n \to \infty} V_T^p(g, \Pi_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t_i \in \Pi_n} |g(t_i \wedge T) - g(t_{i-1} \wedge T)|^p$$

Since $g$ is continuous,

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists\  \delta(\varepsilon): |t_i - t_{i-1}| < \delta(\varepsilon) \implies |g(t_i \wedge T) - g(t_{i-1} \wedge T)| < \varepsilon$$

Now since $|\Pi_n| \to 0$, for every $\varepsilon > 0 \ \exists \ \Pi_n : |\Pi_n| < \delta(\epsilon)$ which implies

$$\sum_{t_i \in \Pi_n} |g(t_i \wedge T) - g(t_{i-1} \wedge T)|^p < \sum_{t_i \in \Pi_n} \varepsilon^p \le M\varepsilon^p$$

Where $M$ is the (finite) number of points in the partition $\Pi_n$ (the number of points is finite because by definition $\Pi_n \cap [0,t]$ is finite for every $t$)

Therefore, since the sum is less that $M\varepsilon^p$ for every positive $\varepsilon$, we conclude that it is $0$.

Except that it is not, as not all continuous function have bounded variation!

So what is the error?

---

This would be true if we also add the hypothesis that $g$ has finite $r$ variations, for $r < p$. But how does the hypothesis enter the argument, and what is wrong with what I've written above?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what $M$ is and why it is always the same number no matter what $\varepsilon$ is?

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Aaaah, I see! $M$ is the number of points in $\Pi_n$ but clearly it depends on $\varepsilon$, so this approach does not work! Thank you :-) Would you also happen to know the proof to show that if we also assume that $g$ has finite $r$ variation, $r < p$, then we really have that the $p$ variation along $\Pi_n$ is $0$? :-)

Comment: I vaguely recall how.  Use uniform continuity of $g$ as you did.  Then you can treat the terms this way:  $$ |g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})|^p \leq |g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})|^{r} \times \varepsilon^{p-r}$$  and that should all work out one hopes.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Great! Thank you :-) If you want to make that an answer, I'll gladly accept it :-)